# Inferring a type from a dereferenced iterator in a template function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, types

I am working through the exercises in "Accelerated C++", and I have discovered some behaviour I do not understand regarding how the compiler infers types in function templates. In exercise 10-2, we are asked to write a template function that can compute the median of a list of arithmetic types in a vector or a built-in array. I stumbled upon an example solution to this problem that involves a template function that computes and returns the median container value between two iterators, i.e. I created the following file called "median.hpp" :

```
#ifndef median_hpp
#define median_hpp

#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

using std::domain_error;
using std::sort;
using std::vector;

template <class T, class Iterator>
T median(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {

  //check if the container is empty
  if (begin == end)
    throw domain_error("median of an empty container");

  //create a vector with the same type as the container
  //and copy the container contents into it 
  vector<T> temp;

  for ( ; begin != end; ++begin)
    temp.push_back(*begin);

  //sort the temporary vector, and compute and return the median
  sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());

  size_t mid = temp.size() / 2;

  T ret = (temp.size() % 2 == 0)
    ? (temp[mid] + temp[mid - 1]) / 2
    : temp[mid];

  return ret;
}

#endif /* median_hpp */
```

so if I wanted to compute, say, the median value of an array and vector to demonstrate that this function works for both container types I would use the aforementioned template function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "median.hpp"

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

    int arr[] = {12,2,4,1,4,56,1};

    const size_t nData = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    vector<double> v(arr, arr + nData);

    cout << median(v.begin(),v.end()) << endl;
    cout << median(arr, arr + nData) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

however, for reasons that I do not understand, I get the following error:

No matching function for call to 'median'... Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'

As far as I can see, the problem is that the compiler is not able to infer the type of "T" from the dereferenced iterators. I would like to know

A. Why is this happening?

B. Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can infer the `Iterator`, but not `T`. That's because the oterator can't say how to infer `T` from anything you pass to it. `Iterator`? From the unknown `Iterator` type, how would you be able to know what `T` is without knowing what `Iterator` actually is? The compiler simply doesn't know that.

However, since you have knowledge that `Iterator` is an actual iterator type, and that most iterator have type-aliases back to the contained type `T` you could do something like

```
template <class Iterator, class T = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>
T median(Iterator begin, Iterator end) { ... }
```

---

Information about all this can be gleaned from e.g. [this `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which tells you that the `iterator` type in the vector is a [*random access iterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) which mentions `value_type` and how it can be found from [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).

[`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) should be possible to use for all standard iterators, not only the random access iterators given by `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no argument of type `T` for `median`, the compiler cannot infer that type.

Solution:

```
template <class Iterator, class T = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>
T median(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    // ....
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd5fbf541b53e75b)</kbd>